# Regexes: the basics of grouping

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I use the following regular expression to match a number and a measurement unit:

```
\d+(?:\.|\,\d+)?[\s-]*(?:\d+)?(?:\/\d+)?(?:cm|mm|ml|cl|l|g|kg)
```

But, when i match something like:

```
22,3 cm
```

it gives me the whole string in first group of matches.

How do I seperate the number and the unit into two different groups?

```
var s1 = @"xxxx 22,3cm";
            var regex1 = new Regex(@"\d+(?:\.|\,\d+)?[\s-]*(?:\d+)?(?:\/\d+)?(?:cm|mm|ml|cl|l|g|kg)",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); 
            var match1 = regex1.Match(s1);
            if (match1.Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(match1.Groups[0].Value); //prints 22,3cm but i need it to print 22,3 only
                Console.WriteLine(match1.Groups[1].Value); //this should print cm
            }
```

Comment: do you expect both values? In your expression it seems one is optional

Comment: @Dalorzo i expect to have the number in the first math group and the unit in the second, note that my regex knowlege is near to zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression **`?:`** above removes what the parenthesis matches from being part of a catching group:

Using your sample a above the two groups you want are: 
**`(\d+(?:\.|\,\d+)?[\s-]*(?:\d+)?(?:\/\d+)?)`** and **`(cm|mm|ml|cl|l|g|kg)`**

Where the second one does not have the `?:`

https://regex101.com/r/oD3wD2/1

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have four non-capturing groups `(?:)`.

It sounds like you want two additional **capturing** groups around certain ones `()`:

```
(\d+(?:\.|\,\d+)?)[\s-]*((?:\d+)?(?:\/\d+)?(?:cm|mm|ml|cl|l|g|kg))
```

Then you can use $1 and $2 to get the quantity and the unit, respectively.

Use http://www.regexr.com/ and other tools to troubleshoot and experiment.

Consider if there is a better library to parse numbers with units.  Writing your own regex to do so is error-prone and more work than you might think.